# No view found for id when trying to start a new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to start a new fragment but my app is crashing saying there is no view found for the id.  The goal is to start this fragment when I click a button

I know this has been asked a lot but nothing I have found was able to fix my issue.

Here is the output:

```
05-22 15:45:11.125 3664-3664/com.example.tanner.sensortesting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.tanner.sensortesting, PID: 3664
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c005f (com.example.tanner.sensortesting:id/sensorLayout) for fragment SensorActivity{2d46a59a #0 id=0x7f0c005f}
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is my main activity.  When I uncomment the second setContentView it works but it places two sensorLayouts slightly off from each other

```
package com.example.tanner.sensortesting;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //setContentView(R.layout.sensor_fragment);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.sensorLayout, new SensorActivity())
                    .commit();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is the fragment I was to start:

```
package com.example.tanner.sensortesting;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by tanner on 5/15/16.
 */
public class SensorActivity extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_fragment, container, false);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    double x = event.values[0];
    double y = event.values[1];
    double z = event.values[2];

    TextView xDegreeTextView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.xDegree);
    TextView yDegreeTextView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.yDegree);
    TextView zDegreeTextView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.zDegree);

    xDegreeTextView.setText(x + "°");
    yDegreeTextView.setText(y + "°");
    zDegreeTextView.setText(z + "°");
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

And finally SensorActivity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tanner.sensortesting.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sensorLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/xDegree"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/yDegree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xDegree"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/zDegree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yDegree"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you should be adding the Fragment to a layout within activity_main.xml, currently your view with id "sensorLayout" is in the layout of the fragment itself.

Try adding a Framelayout with the id "activity_main" to the activity_main.xml instead.

Also,  it would be better to name the Fragment something like SensorFragment.   If you extend Fragment, it is a Fragment.  If you extend Activity, then it would be an Activity.